# Compare two integers using bit operator

Tags: java, integer

I need to compare two integer using Bit operator. 
I faced a problem where I have to compare two integers without using comparison operator.Using bit operator would help.But how?

Lets say 
a = 4;
b = 5;

We have to show  a is not equal to b. 
But,I would like to extend it further ,say,we will show which is greater.Here b is greater..

Comment: Could you please provide an example which describes your problem?

Comment: AFAIK, this is possible in languages (like c) where boolean is represented as int. But not in java, because you can get a boolean value using only comparison. bit operators on int will always only result in an int.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need at least comparison to 0 and notionally this is what the CPU does for a comparison. e.g.

Equals can be modelled as `^` as the bits have to be the same to return 0

```
(a ^ b) == 0
```

if this was `C` you could drop the `== 0` as this can be implied with

```
!(a ^ b)
```

but in Java you can't convert an `int` to a `boolean` without at least some comparison.

For comparison you usually do a subtraction, though one which handles overflows.

```
(long) a - b > 0 // same as a > b
```

subtraction is the same as adding a negative and negative is the same as ~x+1 so you can do

```
(long) a + ~ (long) b + 1 > 0
```

to drop the `+1` you can change this to

```
(long) a + ~ (long) b >= 0 // same as a > b
```

You could implement `+` as a series of bit by bit operations with `>>` `<<` `&` `|` and `^` but I wouldn't inflict that on you.

Comment: This answer has some issues. First, in C, !(a ^ b) is the exact same as (a ^ b) == 0 under the hood. There is no special assembly command that does !a. So you are still doing comparison. You are correct about needing comparison to get boolean in Java from integer but you can actually get 0 or 1 without using comparison. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678344/compare-two-integers-using-bit-operator/66594638#answer-66594638)

Comment: For !a vs a==0, Taken from [C documentation section 6.5.3.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), `The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert `1` or `0` to `bool` without a comparison operator like Peter mentioned. It is still possible to get `max` without a comparison operator.

I'm using `bit` (1 or 0) instead of `int` to avoid confusion.

```
bit msb(x):
    return lsb(x >> 31)
bit lsb(x):
    return x &1

// returns 1 if x < 0, 0 if x >= 0
bit isNegative(x):
    return msb(x)
```

With these helpers `isGreater(a, b)` looks like,

```
// BUG: bug due to overflow when a is -ve and b is +ve
// returns 1 if a > b, 0 if a <= b
bit isGreater_BUG(a, b):
    return isNegative(b - a)    // possible overflow
```

We need two helpers functions to detect same and different signs,

```
// toggles lsb only
bit toggle(x):
    return lsb(~x)

// returns 1 if a, b have same signs (0 is considered +ve).
bit isSameSigns(a, b):
    return toggle(isDiffSigns(a, b))
// returns 1 if a, b have different signs (0 is considered +ve).
bit isDiffSigns(a, b):
    return msb(a ^ b)
```

So with the overflow issue fix,

```
// returns 1 if a > b, 0 if a <= b
bit isGreater(a, b):
    return 
        (isSameSigns(a, b) & isNegative(b - a)) | 
        (isDiffSigns(a, b) & isNegative(b))
```

Note that `isGreater` works correctly for inputs `5, 0` and `0, -5` also.

It's *trickier* to implement `isPositive(x)` properly as `0` will also be considered positive. So instead of using `isPositive(a - b)` above, `isNegative(b - a)` is used as `isNegative(x)` works correctly for `0`.

Now max can be implemented as,

```
// BUG: returns 0 when a == b instead of a (or b)
// returns a if a > b, b if b > a
int max_BUG(a, b):
    return
        isGreater(a, b) * a +   // returns 0 when a = b
        isGreater(b, a) * b     //
```

To fix that, helper `isZero(x)` is used,

```
// returns 1 if x is 0, else 0
bit isZero(x):
    // x | -x will have msb 1 for a non-zero integer
    // and 0 for 0
    return toggle(msb(x | -x))
```

So with the fix when `a = b`,

```
// returns 1 if a == b else 0
bit isEqual(a, b):
    return isZero(a - b) // or isZero(a ^ b)

int max(a, b):
    return
        isGreater(a, b) * a +   // a > b, so a
        isGreater(b, a) * b +   // b > a, so b
        isEqual(a, b) * a       // a = b, so a (or b)
```

That said, if `isPositive(0)` returns 1 then `max(5, 5)` will return 10 instead of 5. So a correct `isPositive(x)` implementation will be,

```
// returns 1 if x > 0, 0 if x <= 0
bit isPositive(x):
    return isNotZero(x) & toggle(isNegative(x))

// returns 1 if x != 0, else 0
bit isNotZero(x):
    return msb(x | -x)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using binary two’s complement notation

```
int findMax( int x, int y)
{
 int z = x - y;
 int i  = (z  >>  31)  &  0x1;
 int  max  =  x - i  *  z;
 return max;
}
```

Reference: [Here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/find-max-without-comparison/)

Comment: Are you suggesting you find a way to avoid doing the comparison in the first place?

Comment: this cannot find if 2 values are equal.

Comment: yes sir, this is the answer to second part : ' But,I would like to extend it further ,say,we will show which is greater.' without comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
a ^ b = c                    // XOR the inputs
                             //  If a equals b, c is zero. Else c is some other value

c[0] | c[1] ... | c[n] = d   // OR the bits
                             //  If c equals zero, d equals zero. Else d equals 1
```

Note: `a,b,c` are n-bit integers and `d` is a bit

Answer (score 0):

The solution in java without using a comparator operator:

```
    int a = 10;
    int b = 12;
    boolean[] bol = new boolean[] {true};

    try {
      boolean c = bol[a ^ b];
      System.out.println("The two integers are equal!");
    } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      System.out.println("The two integers are not equal!");
      int z = a - b;
      int i = (z >> 31) & 0x1;
      System.out.println("The bigger integer is " + (a - i * z));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you need an integer (0 or 1) because you will need a comparison to get a boolean from integer in java.

Here, is a simple solution that doesn't use comparison but uses subtraction which can actually be done using bitwise operations (but not recommended because it takes a lot of cycles in software).

```java
// For equality,
// 1. Perform r=a^b.
//    If they are equal you get all bits 0. Otherwise some bits are 1.
// 2. Cast it to a larger datatype 0 to have an extra bit for sign.
//    You will need to clear the high bits because of signed casting.
//    You can split it into two parts if you can't cast.
// 3. Perform -r.
//    If all bits are 0, you will get 0.
//    If some bits are not 0, then you get a negative number.
// 4. Shift right to extract MSB.
//    This will give -1 (because of sign extension) for not equal and 0 for equal.
//    You can easily convert it to 0 and 1 by adding 1 (I didn't include it in below function).
int equality(int a, int b) {
    long r = ((long)(a^b)) ^0xffffffffl;
    return (int)(((long)-r) >> 63);
}

// For greater_than,
// 1. Cast a and b to larger datatype to get more bits.
//    You can split it into two parts if you can't cast.
// 2. Perform b-a.
//    If a>b, then negative number (MSB is 1)
//    If a<=b, then positive number or zero (MSB is 0)
// 3. Shift right to extract MSB.
//    This will give -1 (because of sign extension) for greater than and 0 for not.
//    You can easily convert it to 0 and 1 by negating it (I didn't include it in below function).
int greater_than(int a, int b) {
    long r = (long)b-(long)a;
    return (int)(r >> 63);
}
```

Less than is similar to greater but you swap a and b.

**Trivia: These comparison functions are actually used in security (Cryptography) because the CPU comparison is not constant-time; aka not secure against timing attacks**.