# How >, >=, <, <= are implemented using only bitwise operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, comparison-operators

I have seen [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67693/comparison-using-only-bitwise-operators-and-return-1-or-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096599/bitwise-operations-equivalent-of-greater-than-operator), from which at least the `>` is obtained as:

```
int isGt(int a, int b)
{
    int diff = a ^ b;
    diff |= diff >> 1;
    diff |= diff >> 2;
    diff |= diff >> 4;
    diff |= diff >> 8;
    diff |= diff >> 16;

    //1+ on GT, 0 otherwise.
    diff &= ~(diff >> 1) | 0x80000000;
    diff &= (a ^ 0x80000000) & (b ^ 0x7fffffff);

    //flatten back to range of 0 or 1.
    diff |= diff >> 1;
    diff |= diff >> 2;
    diff |= diff >> 4;
    diff |= diff >> 8;
    diff |= diff >> 16;
    diff &= 1;

    return diff;
}
```

I am wondering what the equivalent for `>=`, `<`, and `<=` are, and generally a short description of how/why it works. I am trying to figure them out on my own but am having difficulty understanding how this `isGt` works in the first place.

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [bitwise operators for finding less than](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14588160/995714), [Implement greater equal sign in C using only bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13396770/995714), [Bitwise operations equivalent of greater than operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10096599/995714), [Bitwise operation in C to compare two integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46136104/995714), [Replacing "==" with bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4161656/995714), [Compare two integers using bit operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31678344/995714)

Comment: Basically you are computing the difference of a and b then checking for the sign of the difference